# Understanding TypeScript objects with functions

Tags: typescript

I am hoping someone can break this section of code down and help me understand just how this functions.

```
const buildApi = (
  disk: Disk,
  newProp: {
     sector: Sector[]
  }
): ApiDetails => { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign the function to the `buildApi` variable. The function takes two parameters, `disk` of type `Disk`, `newProp` of type (object) `{sector: Sector[]}` and the function is going to return something of type `ApiDetails` the `=>` is the arrow in the arrow function, while everything inside the following `{ }` would become the body of the function.

The above is equivalent of

```
var buildApi = function(disk, newProp) { }
```

or

```
/*
  This is only partially true, as this one would be hoisted, the above isn't
*/
function buildApi(disk, newProp) { }
```

In all cases, you would invoke the function by `buildApi(disk, newProp);`

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for that clear response.